# Why I'm not to use Scroll in Navbar after setAllowScrolling=false in fullpage.js?

Tags: javascript, scroll, fullpage.js

I'm using fullpage.js for sliding full page content but when the navbar is open I need to stop the slider to do scrolling because when I do scroll on the Navbar, the background slide is also getting scrolled.

For this I found a function in fullpage.js API **setAllowScrolling** after setting it false while navbar is open is also not allowing me to scroll inside the navbar.

Any solution regarding this issue because I want to make navbar overflow scroll & stop background
scroll till the navbar is open but after the updated changes Navbar also get freeze with by **setAllowScrolling=false**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to also use the option `normalScrollElements` and pass to it the selector for you scrollable content.

You can read more about this option on the [the fullpage.js documentation](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js).

See a full working demo here:
https://codepen.io/alvarotrigo/pen/QWpBZyB

```js
new fullpage('#fullpage', {
  licenseKey: 'YOUR KEY HERE',
  sectionsColor: ['yellow', 'orange', '#C0C0C0', '#ADD8E6'],
  
  normalScrollElements: '.modal-window'
});

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', openModal);
document.querySelector('.modal-close').addEventListener('click', closeModal);

function openModal(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  fullpage_api.setAllowScrolling(false);
  document.querySelector('.modal-window').classList.add('active');
}

function closeModal(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  fullpage_api.setAllowScrolling(true);
  document.querySelector('.modal-window').classList.remove('active');
}
```

Comment: Thanks I found the answer yesterday forget to mark question as resolved issue. Worked with same implementation of using normalScrollElenent